# How to replace a column in a excel workbook with a dataframe in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I've scraped data from internet and after some operation I've obtained a dataframe like this;

```
    0       1        2           3
3   BAFRA   0   10000   0.114705
4   BAFRA   100001  300000  0.114705
1   BAFRA   300001  1000000 0.114705
0   BAFRA   1000001 10000000    0.114705
2   BAFRA   10000001    100000000   0.114705
5   BAFRA   100000000   100000001   0.114705
```

What I want is take the third column and replace it in exist excel file in a specific sheet and to a specific column and row.
I am using this code;

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(...\Gas Settlement Aug20.xlsx",engine="openpyxl") as writer:  
    df[3].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Unit Prices',header= False, index = False, startcol=12,startrow=24)
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(...\Gas Settlement Aug20.xlsx")
ws = wb['Unit Prices']
wb.save(...\Gas Settlement Aug20.xlsx")
```

But it delete all the information, I tried the mode 'a' but this time it creates a new sheet.
Is there any way to replace my old data with the new ones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using two different approaches at once: pd.ExcelWriter and openpyxl.
Just following the sample you provided you can use openpyxl like this to update your file:

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("...\Gas Settlement Aug20.xlsx")
ws = wb['Unit Prices']
startcol = 12
startrow = 24
for item in df[3]:
    ws.cell(startrow, startcol).value = item
    startrow +=1
wb.save(...\Gas Settlement Aug20.xlsx")
```

But I suggest that you don't use this form of indexing with numbers, because it is easy to create errors, and very hard to find those errors. Depending on the size, even reading the whole file, updating and saving again would be much safer and easier to track.

Comment: This code is worked. Thank you so much , indexing with number is only way that I know I still trying to improve my skills. Thanks again!!!